# Capture a value outputted in terminal with php

Tags: php, terminal

I have this function:

```
exec("sudo /root/modbus/writeForceReg 2 0");
```

located in a php script. When I execute the script in terminal, it returns either 1 or -1 in the terminal window. My question is how to capture and store these two values in a variable in the same php script?

Comment: Take a look into the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` provides a second parameter which can be used to get the output of the process

```
exec("sudo /root/modbus/writeForceReg 2 0", $output);
```

If the application is using the stderr instead of stdout you need to use proc_open:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php